# Belphegor prime number problem with Python

Tags: python

I have seen a video about Belphegor prime numbers. The definition of a Belphegor prime is one such that in the expression `(10^(n+3)+666)*(10^(n+1)+1)` is prime for `n` being a positive integer.

I tried making a Python program that would determine whether an input number `n` will produce a prime number in the expression mentioned before but my code said that for all `n` in the expression would be prime which is not true and it said it indefinitely.

My code:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a positive number n: "))

x =(10**(n+3)+666)*10**(n+1)+1

for i in range(2,x - 1):
    if x % i == 0:
        print("Composite")
    else:
        print("Belphegor prime")
```

Please help me fix this error!

Comment: what was the input given by you, and what was the error

Comment: I think you forgot some brackets: `x =(10**(n+3)+666)*(10**(n+1)+1)`

Comment: Have you tried walking through the execution of your code on paper/in your head?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your code prints out either `Composite` or `Prime` on every iteration through the loop. Instead, you need to assume the number is prime and if at any time the test fails, set a flag to false; then use the state of the flag at the end of the loop to determine if the number is actually prime:

```
from math import sqrt

n = int(input("Enter a positive number n: "))
x =(10**(n+3)+666)*(10**(n+1)+1)   
p = True
for i in range(2,int(sqrt(x))+1):
    if x % i == 0:
        p = False
        break
if p:
    print("Belphegor prime")
else:
    print("Composite")
```

Note you can shorten your loop by only iterating as far as `sqrt(x)` as any number greater than `sqrt(x)` which is a divisor of `x` will have a matching divisor less than `sqrt(x)`.

Note also that as @LeoE pointed out in the comments to your question, you are missing some `()` in your computation of `x`.